# Microsoft Internet Explorer: "Your browser does not support this video codec (wmv, flv)"

Tags: video, internet-explorer, codec

I'm trying to watch the video in Internet Explorer 11 x64 (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate). I have the following error message: "*Your browser does not support this video codec (wmv, flv)*". How can I solve this issue without switching browser? (*)

[image]

(*) I need to stay on Internet Explorer 11 as I want to use [StreamTransport](http://www.streamtransport.com/) to download the video, and it uses Internet Explorer 11 to get the video stream.

Edit: My MSIE add-ons: I have 32-bit Adobe Flash but no 64-bit Adobe Flash. Installing [64-bit Adobe Flash](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) solved the issue.

[image]

PS: to know whether Internet Explorer (aka. MSIE) 11 is 32-bit or 64-bit, on a 64-bit Windows:

- if MSIE is in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, then it is 32-bit
- if MSIE is in `C:\Program Files`, then it is 64-bit.

Also, the shortcut in the start menu sometimes indicate 32 or 64.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Internet Explorer 11? If so, make sure you have 64-bit Adobe Flash installed.

Comment: The simplest solution.  Install the required codec.  The said codec will need to support being a plug-in for IE.

Comment: @allquixotic Good catch, I was using 64-bit Internet Explorer 11 with  32-bit Adobe Flash. Installing 64-bit Adobe Flash solved the issue, thanks! Can you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using 64-bit Internet Explorer 11? If so, make sure you have 64-bit Adobe Flash installed. Like goes with like: for 64-bit IE, you need 64-bit Flash; for 32-bit IE, you need 32-bit Flash. You can have both installed on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

### Make sure that add-ons are installed and enabled

Make sure that the necessary add-ons are enabled in Internet Explorer. To do this, follow these steps:

- On the **Tools** menu in Internet Explorer, click **Internet Options**.
- Click the **Programs** tab, and then click **Manage add-ons**.
- In the **Currently loaded add-ons list**, click **Run without Permissions**.
- Look for the following add-ons in the list that's displayed. If any of these add-ons are listed, make sure the **Status** for each is listed as **Enabled**.

  - Shockwave Active X Control
  - Shockwave Flash Object
  - Java Plug-in (may be multiple add-ons)
  - QuickTime Plug-in (may be multiple add-ons)
  - Windows Media Player

For more info, refer **[Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2532294)**

### Update:

### Why won't videos play in Internet Explorer 11?

Many websites use add-ons such as Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, or QuickTime to play video or audio files. Instead of using add-ons Internet Explorer streams media content using HTML5 and Adobe Flash on compatible sites. If video won't play, try opening the site using Internet Explorer for the desktop.

For more info, refer **[Microsoft Support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/videos-dont-work#ie=ie-11)**

Comment: Thanks, your answer allowed me to see that I had 32-bit Adobe Flash but was missing 64-bit Adobe Flash. Installing the later solved the issue.